# How do I convert this input to lowercase (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I convert the input to lowercase so that the input isn't case sensitive?

```
        # Handle user inputs
    
    # Function to return a valid input
    def GetInput():
        print("1) Option A")
        print("2) Option B")
        Valid = False
        Choice = ""
        while not Valid:
            Choice = input("Enter an option number: ")
            if Choice == "A" or Choice == "B":
                    Valid = True
            else:
                print("Invalid option chosen. Try again.")
        return Choice
    
    # Main program
    Choice = GetInput()
    print("You chose option {}".format(Choice))
    
    #UpperCase To LowerCase
    string = "this should be all uppercase."
    print(string.swapcase())
```

I am quite new to programming and have been stuck on this for a while.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Not related to your question, but since you said you are new to programming you might want to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

Each input would be a string, and there is an inner function in string named `lower`:

```py
print(input("your input: ").lower())
```

##### Output

```
your input: My INPUT
my input
```